# Can I change column order in SQL table based on a value that appears in different columns?

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3| Column4
    4   |    3    |    2   |    1
    2   |    1
    3   |    2    |    1
```

I want to flip the columns so that 1 always start in column 1 and then the rest of the values follow to the right. Like this:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4
    1   |    2    |    3    |   4
    1   |    2    
    1   |    2    |    3
```

This is an example table. The real table is a hierarchy of a company so 1 = CEO and 2 = SVP for example. 1 is always the same name but as the number gets higher (lower in chain of command) the more names that are in that level. I'm hoping for an automated solution that looks for 1, makes that the first column and then populates the columns. I am struggling because the value that 1 represents is in different columns so I can't just change the order of the columns.

I was able to accomplish this using VBA but I would prefer to keep it in SQL.

I don't have any useful code that I have tried so far.

Comment: Why do you have different columns when you don't bother where data is stored?

Comment: Hmmm... I suppose if you are populating a table of results in code you can do whatever you want however I'm curious to know whether or not you are querying an actual table in a database that contains actual data?  Are you pulling this data from actual rows inside a database table?  I ask this as Column1 will always be Column1 and the data in the rows in that column from your table will always be the same.  You can of course add conditional logic using a CASE Statement perhaps to get the output of the data to be anything you want/need it to be.

Comment: Columns are always populated from left to right with trailing NULLs? Is the data calculated or do those it exists as-is? And what's your DBMS?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Case expression:

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(SELECT 4 AS COL1, 3  AS COL2 , 2 AS COL3, 1 AS COL4 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 2, 1, NULL FROM DUAL
)
SELECT CASE WHEN COL1 <> 1 THEN 1 ELSE COL1 END AS COL1,
CASE WHEN COL2 <> 2 THEN 2 ELSE COL2 END AS COL2,
CASE WHEN COL3 <> 3 THEN 3 ELSE COL3 END AS COL3,
CASE WHEN COL4 <> 4 THEN 4 ELSE COL4 END AS COL4
FROM CTE1;
```

Comment: Thanks Atif. I should have been more clear in my question (first one). This is an example table. The real table is a hierarchy of a company so 1 = CEO and 2 = SVP for example. 1 is always the same name but as the number gets higher (lower in chain of command) the more names that are in that level. I can't explicitly use a Case because what I described as a value of "2" will actually be different values but represent the same level. So maybe 2.1 and 2.2 would have been a better way describe this. I updated my question.

Comment: Its better if you can provide more realistic data with dummy values

Answer (score 0):

You can apply some CASEes checking all possibilities, this is assuming NULLs for missing data:

```
COALESCE(col4,col3,col2,col1) AS c1,

CASE
    WHEN col4 IS NOT NULL THEN col3
    WHEN col3 IS NOT NULL THEN col2
    WHEN col2 IS NOT NULL THEN col1
END AS c2,
    
CASE
    WHEN col4 IS NOT NULL THEN col2
    WHEN col3 IS NOT NULL THEN col1
END AS c3,
    
CASE
    WHEN col4 IS NOT NULL THEN col1
END AS c4
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to sort the values.  A generic SQL solution would use:

```
select max(case when seqnum = 1 then col end) as col1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then col end) as col2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then col end) as col3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then col end) as col4
from (select col1, col2, col3, col4, col,
             row_number() over (order by col) as seqnum
      from ((select col1 as col, 1 as which, col1, col2, col3, col4 from t) union all
            (select col2 as col, 2 as which, col1, col2, col3, col4 from t) union all
            (select col3 as col, 3 as which, col1, col2, col3, col4 from t) union all
            (select col4 as col, 4 as which, col1, col2, col3, col4 from t)
           ) t
      where col is not null
     ) t
group by col1, col2, col3, col4;
```

This would be simpler in a database that supports lateral joins.  And a unique id on each row would also help.